# Нужна помощь с C# и OLEDB

Tags: c#, oledb

Пишу приложение на c#, после смены версии сервера (sql), стала выходить ошибка:

> Index #0
> Message: Invalid object name '##tmp_DBF'.
> Native: 208
> Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
> SQL: 42S02

С чем связано не могу понять, прошу помочь, прикладываю часть кода ниже:

```
OleDbConnection conn2 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " + pricePath + " ;Extended Properties=DBASE IV;Persist Security Info=False;");
conn2.Open();
OleDbCommand comm = conn2.CreateCommand();

if (proname == "NULL")
{
    comm.CommandText = $"SELECT " + skucode + ", " + skuname + ", " + qnt + ", " + price + ", " + barcode + " FROM priceDBF";
}
else
{
    comm.CommandText = $"SELECT " + skucode + ", " + skuname + ", " + qnt + ", " + price + ", " + barcode + ", " + proname + " FROM priceDBF";
}

comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OleDbDataReader reader_con2 = comm.ExecuteReader();

OleDbCommand oleDbxls = new OleDbCommand();
oleDbxls.Connection = myConnection;

oleDbxls.CommandText = $"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##tmp_DBF; " +
                       $"CREATE TABLE [##tmp_DBF] (priceId INT, skuId VARCHAR(50), skuName VARCHAR(250), qty INT, price FLOAT, barcode VARCHAR(50), name_pro VARCHAR(MAX)) ";
Thread.Sleep(1000);
oleDbxls.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Ошибка выдается после выполнения этого куска кода:

```
OleDbCommand oleDb_add = new OleDbCommand();
oleDb_add.Connection = myConnection;
oleDb_add.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ##tmp_DBF(priceId, skuId, skuName, qty, price, barcode, name_pro) VALUES" +
                                                    $"({idPrice},N'{skucode_dbf}',N'{skuname_dbf.Replace("'", "")}','{qnt_dbf}','{price_dbf}',N'{barcoderead_dbf}',N'{proname_dbf.Replace("\"", " ").Replace("'", "")}')";
oleDb_add.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: С какой версии на какую перешли?

Comment: Освобождения ресурсов нет (`using`, `Dispose`), sql-запросы делаются конкатенацией строк - тут ничем не поможешь...

Comment: Вероятно, сессия закрылась, а с ней и временная таблица удалилась. / Либо тщательней следите за соединениями (connection), либо не используйте временные таблицы.